# SETF neither terminates nor reports an error

Tags: common-lisp, setf

I'm a Common Lisp beginner and came across this piece of code:

```
(let ((foo (list 42)))
  (setf (rest foo) foo))
```

The REPL seem to just loop forever when trying to execute it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### What is `FOO`?

`FOO` is initially a fresh list, `(42)`. In Lisp, lists are represented by [cons cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR), blocks of mutable memory containing each a `CAR` and a `CDR` slot. 
Another way to print it is `(42 . NIL)`, where the `CAR` and `CDR` are on each side of the dot. This can also be pictured as follows:

```
  car  cdr
------------
| 42 | NIL |
------------
     ^
     |
    FOO
```

When you call [`SETF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_setf_.htm) with the `(rest foo)` *place* and the `foo` value, you are saying that you want the *cdr* cell of `FOO` to hold the value `FOO`. In fact, this occurrence of `SETF` is likely to macroexpand into a call to [`RPLACD`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm).

```
------------
| 42 | FOO |
------------
     ^
     |
    FOO
```

#### Why does the REPL loop forever?

The "P" part of the "REPL" (print) tries to print your circular structure.  This is because `SETF`'s value is the one being returned from the form being evaluated, and the value returned by `SETF` is the value of its second argument, namely `FOO`. Imagine you want to write a cons cell X with a naive algorithm:

```
1. PRINT "("
2. PRINT the CAR of X
3. PRINT " . "
4. PRINT the CDR of X
5. PRINT ")"
```

However, for `foo`, step 4 will print the same structure, recursively, and will never terminate.

#### What can you do?

Try setting [`*PRINT-CIRCLE*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) to T  first:

```
(setf *print-circle* t)
```

And now, your REPL should be happy:

```
CL-USER> (let ((foo (list 42)))
           (setf (rest foo) foo))
#1=(42 . #1#)
```

The ["Sharpsign Equal-Sign"](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dho.htm) notation allows the reader to affect part of a form to a (reader) variable, like `#1=...`, and reuse it afterwards, e.g. `#1#`. This make it possible to represent circular cross-references between data, either during reading or printing. Here, we can see that the variable `#1#` denotes a cons-cell, where the `CAR` is 42 and the `CDR` is `#1#` itself.

Comment: beautiful answer!